# How can we change the number of products per page when using Vacuum gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, rubygems

I'm using the [Vacuum gem](https://github.com/hakanensari/vacuum) and want to display 12 products per page, but I always get 10 products.

I also tried to use batch code with 'item_search', but didn't work.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: The Vacuum tag you used is not actually the API wrapper, just to let you know. Doesn't look like such a tag exists. If you want, look at the other amazon tags and see if any of them are an appropriate fit.

Comment: @PaulRichter: I didn't create the tag.

Comment: I know you didn't, I was just letting you know it wasn't the correct tag, even though it had the same name as the gem. Looks like you and someone have already retagged this; good luck in your search.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html), ItemSearch returns up to ten search results per page. So, we've to store the result in an array and then process for next page, store the 2 results in previous array, and so on...